# Mysterious scheme procedure for cycling through lists

Tags: list, scheme, racket, mutable, circular-reference

There is this procedure giving me trouble:

```
(define (pro lst)
  (define (inner l)
    (if (null? (mcdr l))
        (set-mcdr! l lst)
        (inner (mcdr l))))
  (inner lst)
  lst)
```

Using (mlist 1 2 3) as parameter I get #0={1 2 3 . #0#} returned.
`(mcdr (pro (mlist 1 2 3)))` returns #0={2 3 1 . #0#},
`(mcdr (mcdr (pro (mlist 1 2 3))))` returns #0={3 1 2 . #0#} and so on.

So obviously this is for cycling through lists by returning a pair of a list and another procedure. But how does this work? I only see that it replaces the final'() with the parameter lst but not with any obscure lambda function ...
What do #0 and #0# mean anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the expression `#0={1 2 3 . #0#}`, think of `#0=` as an anchor and `#0#` as a link to that anchor - that is, in the list the first three elements are `1 2 3` but the fourth element is a pointer to the start of the list, therefore forming a three-element circular list. If you keep advancing over that list (by successive `mcdr`s), you'll see a three element list in a cycling pattern `1 2 3 1 2 3 ...`, always showing that the fourth element jumps back to the first.

Studying the above function makes it clear why this is happenning. The `pro` procedure simply calls `inner` on the `lst` parameter (a proper list, a list with `null` as its last element) and then returns the modified `lst`, the interesting part is what happens in `inner`:

- `(if (null? (mcdr l))`: If we're on the last non-null element of the list, replace the next element (which should be a `null` in a proper list), by a reference to the first element, which we know is in the `lst` parameter: `(set-mcdr! l lst)`
- Otherwise, keep advancing over the list: `(inner (mcdr l))`

To summarize: the `pro` procedure gets as its input a proper list and returns the same list but with the last element pointing back to its first element - a circular list.

Answer (score 2):

The `#0=` indicates a shared marker to some data, and `#0#` indicates a reference to the data previously marked. See the examples at the bottom of http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/shared.html . Your function doesn't return a pair of things, just a single value - the last expression in the body of the definition, which is lst. But as you perhaps realize, the `lst` at the end has potentially been mutated so that it is different than what it was when initially passed to the function. (You use the term "cycling" which is exactly what this function does, but not quite in the sense that you've applied it in your question.)